# Xamarin and sending logs to email

Tags: android, logging, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Xamarin Android application and I would like to send application's logs to email (information about exceptions, stacktraces, etc). But  I don't know how to do it properly. I dont't want to reinvent the wheel and i I would like to use appropriate libraries. As I know Xamarin.Inights is perfect tool for my purpose. Unfortunatelly it isn't free.

Is there any ideas for solving my problem? What is a common solution for it in Xamarin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/pricing/) does this, and is free for up to 2 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jason's reply.

With Hockeyapp Xamarin SDK, you could collect following data via your free account:

--Crash data, including stack trace, exceptions

--User metric

--in-app updtate

--in-app feedback

You could find detailed tutorial from [GH](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Xamarin):

If you have any further questions, please consult with the support team on the [HA forum](https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems).